# Вывести все поля таблицы с последним временем каждого логина

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица, хранящая: **Время**, **Логин пользователя**.

Пример:

> 20:00:00  |  Name1
>
> 20:02:00  |  Name2
>
> 20:03:00  |  Name1

Необходимо вывести все поля таблицы с последним временем каждого логина. Т.е. после выборки должно получиться:

> 20:02:00  |  Name2
>
> 20:03:00  |  Name1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select login, max(time)
from table
group by login
```

[Группировка](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html)

Comment: блин, точно ) совсем забыл про группировку, спасибо :)